# Hints/Tipps/Advices for beginning student of proof theory

Tags: logic

Not an exact question really yet, but just already getting a picture about where/how I will probably find help, advices, hints etc. in the next weeks and months.

In the following months I will be studying proof theory, following the book of Girard from 86, and I guess I will often not fully understand the arguments (and other thoughts) involved and fail on the exercises too.

So if you happen to read this and if you are experiencend and/or interested in the subject please leave me a note.

All the best, Ettore

Comment: [The Development of Proof Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory-development/).

Comment: [Proof-Theoretic Semantics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theoretic-semantics/).

Comment: Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=QrdEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PR5) (2013).

Comment: Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, [Structural Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZvACGkn9138C&printsec=frontcover) (2001).

Comment: Katalin Bimbo, [Proof Theory: Sequent Calculi and Related Formalisms](https://books.google.it/books?id=ulzOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR7) (2015).

Comment: Heinrich Wansing (editor), [Dag Prawitz on Proofs and Meaning](https://books.google.it/books?id=GfObBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR7) (2013).

Comment: Hi Mauro, thanks for your comprehensive reading list! Can you tell me something about them, like why you are suggesting them, or in what sense. Which of them you value most or somehow specifically? Would you not advice me to try it with Girards book? I don't have much of a reason to try it with Girard, its a pretty wild guess, it seemed OK though. 1 or 2 years ago I had a look into Takeuti, but didn't get a clue.

Comment: Sorry again for originally not having been specific in a question, I understand that this is not how the forum is intended, in future I will come up with concrete problems.

Comment: No problem with Takeuti or Girard... I think that they are more "advanced". The SEP's entries are for an overview while the textbooks are listed in order of "increasing complexity" (IMO).

Comment: OK I see, thanks.